# Transforming google maps waypoint directions to via-directions

Tags: java, google-maps

I am trying to change the URL of google maps directions from directions which have multiple waypoints to directions where these intermediate waypoints are deleted but the route remains the same.

Specifically from: https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/51.804323,5.8061076/51.8059489,5.7971745/51.8095767,5.8032703/@51.8068221,5.806553,16.5z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2

to:
https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/51.804323,5.8061076/51.8095767,5.8032703/@51.8069622,5.8023697,17z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m5!3m4!1m2!1d5.7971218!2d51.8060231!3s0x47c7061292e15b39:0x4d7bcd7484c71cf3!1m0!3e2

**EDIT: because I had to drag the route manually in the second URL the coordinates of the middle marker are not exactly the same as in the first URL; this difference can be ignored.**

the start part of these URLS seem pretty obvious as to what they are doing, however the data parameter is still unclear to me (without it the route is not correct). I tried the Google Maps API, but these return an XML or JSON file, but I just need the corresponding URL which I would also get using the webinterface of Google Maps.

How can I tranform the first URL to the second??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a long time trying to figure out how the URL scheme works, I finally figured out how it works (for the directions interface).

The URL consists of the following steps:

1. You start off with "https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/"
2. This is followed by the start coordinates in the form "[LAT],[LONG]", the coordinates of intermediate waypoints in the same format,and then the coordinates of end points. All these coordinates are seperated by a "/" character.
3. This is followed by "@[LAT],[LONG],[ZOOM]/" where LAT LONG are the coordinates of the viewbox and ZOOM is the level of zoom (lower means more zoomed out).
4. This is followed by "data=" and then "!4m[(5x+4+y)]!4m[(5x+3+y)]!" where x is the amount of VIA-points and y is the amount of intermediate waypoints in the route. So if you have a route from A to D with intermediate destinations B and C and VIA points Q, W and R you have x=3 and y=2 so you get the string "!4m21!4m20"
5. Next we get all VIA points. This done in the following scheme: you append "!1m[(5x)]" where x is the amount of VIA-points between the current waypoint and the next. So "!1m5...[data]...!1m0" means that between the start and first waypoint there is one VIA-point and between the first waypoint and the end there are no VIA-points. Each "!1m[(5x)]" is followed by x instances of "!1d[LONG]!2d[LAT]!3s[COORDINATE]". I am not entirely sure what COORDINATE does, but is has to be in the format "0x[HEX]:0x[HEX]" where HEX is a hexadecimal number; I simply take the number 0 for this. This seems to work in all my test cases and does not seem to influence anything.
6. This is then followed by "!1m0". I believe this is necessary to indicate that after the last waypoint (the finish) there are no more VIA points, which is useless information but needed nevertheless.
7. Finally, we get the last parameter which looks like "!3e[n]" where n is a discrete variable to indicate the type of navigation: n=0 for driving by car,n=1 is for bicycle riding, n=2 is for walking, and n=3 for public transportation.

That is mostly it for what I found out about the URL scheme by testing it relentlessly. There are more parameters you can add, but that needs more work testing.

Finally, I included my implementation for transforming a URL with 0 or more waypoints and 0 or more VIA-points to a URL containing only VIA-points. Feel free to use it and please let me know if you have found any mistakes so I can fix them.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter URL: ");
    String originalURL = br.readLine();

    //get start of URL
    String start = "https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/";

    //get navigation type
    String type = "!3e1";
    Matcher t = getMatcher(originalURL, "!3e\\d");
    if (t.find()) {
        type = t.group();
    }

    //get viewbox parameter
    Matcher v = getMatcher(originalURL, "@[-]?[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+,[-]?[\\d]+.[\\d]+,[-]?[\\d]+[[.]+[\\d]+]*z");
    v.find();
    String viewbox = v.group();

    //get order of points when using VIA
    String data = originalURL.substring(originalURL.indexOf("/data=") + 6);
    ArrayList<String> order = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher o = getMatcher(data, "!1m[\\d]+");
    while (o.find()) {
        order.add(o.group());
    }
    if (order.size() > 0) {
        //remove the last element which is always m0 as this should not be
        //displayed in the VIA-list
        order.remove(order.size() - 1);
    }

    //!1m2 does not represent the order but indicates that coordinates that are coming up
    order.removeIf(a -> a.equals("!1m2"));

    //get coordinates of via-points
    ArrayList<String> originalViaPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher c = getMatcher(data, "!1d[-]?[\\d]+.[\\d]+!2d[-]?[\\d]+.[\\d]+");
    while (c.find()) {
        String[] g = c.group().substring(3).split("!2d");
        originalViaPoints.add(g[1] + "," + g[0]);
    }

    //get coordinates of start, end and intermediate points
    originalURL = originalURL.substring(0, v.start());
    ArrayList<String> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher p = getMatcher(originalURL, "[-]?[\\d]+\\.[\\d]+,[-]?[\\d]+.[\\d]+");
    while (p.find()) {
        waypoints.add(p.group());
    }
    //start and end must be displayed seperately
    String bound = waypoints.get(0) + "/" + waypoints.get(waypoints.size() - 1);

    //add intermediate waypoints and via-points to a list of VIA points
    ArrayList<String> viaPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    //we have VIA points to process
    if (!order.isEmpty()) {
        int via_index = 0;
        int wp_index = 1;
        for (String step : order) {
            int iter = Integer.valueOf(step.substring(3)) / 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
                viaPoints.add(originalViaPoints.get(via_index++));
            }
            viaPoints.add(waypoints.get(wp_index++));
        }
    } else //There are only waypoints in the URL
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < waypoints.size() - 1; i++) {
            viaPoints.add(waypoints.get(i));
        }
    }

    //calculate prefix according to the amount of nodes of the via points
    int nodes = viaPoints.size();
    String prefix = "!4m" + (5 * nodes + 4) + "!4m" + (5 * nodes + 3) + "!1m" + (5 * nodes);

    //get nodes string
    String viaString = "";
    for (String node : viaPoints) {
        viaString += "!3m4!1m2";
        String[] pieces = node.split(",");
        viaString += "!1d" + pieces[1]; //ALERT: the coordinates are flipped!
        viaString += "!2d" + pieces[0];
        viaString += "!3s0x0:0x0";
    }

    String url = start + bound + "/" + viewbox + "/data=" + prefix + viaString + "!1m0" + type;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters), in the old url scheme, there should be 3 ways to add a via point or a route, and they are:

> https://www.google.com/maps?dirflg=w&saddr=51.804323,5.8061076&daddr=51.8059489,5.7971745+to:51.8095767,5.8032703
>
> https://www.google.com/maps?dirflg=w&saddr=51.804323,5.8061076&daddr=51.8095767,5.8032703&mrad=51.8059489,5.7971745
>
> https://www.google.com/maps?dirflg=w&saddr=51.804323,5.8061076&daddr=51.8095767,5.8032703&via=51.8059489,5.7971745

But it seems they dropped support to mrad and via. And for using to, it shows the address as if it would be shown in the new url scheme.

For the new URL scheme.. it does not seems to have a lot of documentation on it, so I am not sure if Google wants you to play with it. but... here it is: How to do it with the new scheme.

according to [this blog post](https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters):

[image]

the `!xx`, is a separator. Looking at your url:

```
data=
!4m9
!4m8
!1m5
!3m4
!1m2
!1d5.7971218
!2d51.8060231
!3s0x47c7061292e15b39:0x4d7bcd7484c71cf3
!1m0
!3e2
```

it is really unclear what it is doing, but, at least we see your via lat, and via lng in the `!1d` and `!2d` fields;
Also the `!3s`, in a hex format looks like some kind of lat/lng, might be the area of search. This is how it looks like in dec `5172109373901724473:5583282063383403763`

Well, in short, just change the `!1d` and `!2d` fields and it seems to work fine. like this: 
https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/51.804323,5.8061076/51.8095767,5.8032703/@51.8769532,5.8550939,7.58z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m5!3m4!1m2!1d5.871218!2d52.8060231!3s0x47c7061292e15b39:0x4d7bcd7484c71cf3!1m0!3e2

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, but unfortunately I still have a problem concerning the number of points; I cannot add an intermediate point to the directions I already have. In short, I would like to obtain a URL from A to B with multiple intermediate destinations and create a new URL with the intermediate destinations removed and added to the route as "via"-points. So the algorithm should work with any number of intermediate destinations.

Comment: ummm.. I have no idea too. playing with the google maps, it turns out that `!3m4!1m2!1d5.871218!2d52.8060231!3s0x47c7061292e15b39:0x4d7bcd7484c71cf3` represent a point, and Google maps seems to be stacking up the point one after another. However when I try to add a point, and make the path to have n+1 viewpoints, Google Maps would reject the API. I am guessing that there might have something to do with the hex value. However, if you have a path with n checkpoints in between, it seems you can just modify the lat/lng freely.

Comment: I think I almost solved it now after playing around with the parameters. For each point we use the !3m4!1m2 prefix, followed by the !1d and the !2d for the coordinates. Then a !3s code comes and it seems that this can be !3s0x0:0x0 but this needs some more testing. It seems that the data tag finishes with !1m0 followed by !3e2 for walking directions and !3e1 for bycicle directions. Now the prefix is a bit weird (and needs some more testing) The data part seems to be !4m(5x+4)!4m(5x+3)!4m(5x) where you need to evaluate the part between the brackets.